# Do we really need the tag 'chess'?

Tags: discussion, tags

Chess is a specific classic board game.

And we have a tag for it: [chess](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess).

It has only 11 questions.

What should we do with it?

Comment: and a single 1-rep-guy posted 2 out of 11 super downvoted questions

Comment: I believe it's a little bit too bit too concise and underused to be a tag.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good tag and we should keep it.

It is a board game, but it is also a board game that is very commonly adapted as a video game, and there are lots of algorithms and techniques for doing so efficiently (particularly within the domains of board representation and AI).

I think it's quite reasonable to expect that somebody who is an expert at writing chess AI or solvers, or somebody interested in finding questions and solutions about such problems, would be the kind of person to make [chess](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) a favorite.

I *don't* think the current description of the tag is worthwhile though. It describes the game in detail, but not how the tag should be used in the context of Game Development.

Comment: reality shows that there are only 11 questions. Among them only 2 look interesting and not even too much related to chess, rather to generic algorithms. This tag adds entropy to the site. Just a drop into the ocean, but since we are talking about it..

Comment: by the way I get your point that chess is more than a game, close to an intitution

Comment: *Popularity* is not a good metric for determining whether a tag is good for the site or not, it's just a factor for how careful we should be when considering doing something to the tag (for example, we should be *extremely* careful doing something to [tag:unity]). If only having 11 questions means a tag is bad, well, we should remove every tag right? Because every tag with more than 11 questions had 11 questions at some point. Just because something is new, or unpopular or its popularity grows slowly *should not* be a reason to blacklist it.

Comment: What we should consider is: is the tag on-topic (absolutely, no question about it) and is the tag contextually specific enough that people would be able to use it for searches or filters and get results that make sense and are consistent (in this case, finding Q&A about writing chess games). I don't really see how chess is different from `racing` or `roguelike` or anything else that's isolating scope to a subgenre. You can be a chess game expert.

Comment: I thought about posting a second answer, and suggesting to make it a synonym of [tag:board-game].

Answer (score 2):

I think we should delete it.

Given the fact that is *very* specific, and even though one could be expert at chess (at *playing* it), the challenges at implementing it is not more and not less difficult than any other games.